# ValueError found while trying to use pandas for multiple regression

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying to run a simple multiple linear regression program using panda with a large dataset, but I'm getting an error that says:
`ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

The code is:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('manydatas.csv')

x = data[['Bedrooms', 'City', 'Age']]
y = data['Selling Price']

line = linear_model.LinearRegression(x,y)

line.fit(x,y)
```

I'd appreciate any help with this, thanks

Edit: Here is a drive link to the .csv file with my data, there are over a thousand elements so I'm just linking the whole thing: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VCNJZNKYRmUd7A6qQlDnzTbiO_7x7I3s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you tried converting x to a numpy array?

Comment: I'll add the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use your data inside model constructor

```
line = linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

To do linear regression, you must use `linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(X, y)`, not  `linear_model.LinearRegression(x,y)`. If the issue still persists, try converting the data to a numpy array. (source: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html)